# Is there a standard way to display the play controls that the iPhone iPod app uses?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface

I'm working on a music streaming app that needs play controls (skip, pause, play) just like the iPhone iPod app.  I built my controls using a UIToolbar and the standard buttons.

My UIToolbar controls look OK, but they're smaller than the ones that the iPod uses.

Does anyone know if the iPod controls are custom graphics?  Or maybe custom buttons in a UIToolbar (to get the gradient)?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting, I found custom buttons in a UIToolbar look pretty good.  They only need to be white 24bit PNGs, and this saves you from building your own interface from a plain UIView.